# How do I compute the arcot (inverse cotangent) in PHP?

Tags: php, math

PHP has many builtin trig math functions, but the inverse cotangent does not seem to be available as one of them. This is also referred to as arccot. Does anyone have the function equivalent in PHP to compute this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `arctan` in PHP?  Given `x` and you want to computer `arccot(x)`, you could compute `arctan(1/x)` since this equals `arccot(x)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can [use *arctan(x)* to calculate *arccot(x)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arccot):

```
function acot(x) {
  return pi()/2 - atan(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Math_Complex` PEAR package to do that: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.math.math-complex.math-complexop.acot.php